# Any way to only extract specific div from beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have run into an issue while working on a web scraping project in python. I am new to python and am not sure how to extract a specific line, or a value from part of a line, from the beautiful soup output. I would like to get only the data-rarity part from this site but i haven't found how to do that without removing the entire line from the list.

Any help is much appreciated!

I have this:

```
rarity = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'profileCards__card'})
print(rarity[0])
```

This outputs:

```
<div class="profileCards__card  upgrade " data-level="902" data-elixir="2" data-rarity="102" data-arena="802">
<a href="https://statsroyale.com/card/Giant+Snowball"><img src="//cdn.statsroyale.com/images/cards/full/snowball.png"><span class="profileCards__level">lvl.9</span></a>
<div class="profileCards__meter">
<span style="width: 100%"></span>
<div class="profileCards__meter__numbers">
8049/800
</div>
</div>
<div class="ui__tooltip ui__tooltipTop ui__tooltipMiddle cards__tooltip">
Giant Snowball
</div>
</div>
```

I would ideally want to get only the value after the data-rarity so just the 102 part from this in the inspect element of the site.

```
<div class="profileCards__cards">
<div class="profileCards__card  upgrade " data-level="902" data-elixir="2" data-rarity="102" data-arena="802">
<a href="https://statsroyale.com/card/Giant+Snowball"><img src="//cdn.statsroyale.com/images/cards/full/snowball.png"><span class="profileCards__level">lvl.9</span></a>
<div class="profileCards__meter">
<span style="width: 100%"></span>
<div class="profileCards__meter__numbers">
8049/800
</div>
</div>
<div class="ui__tooltip ui__tooltipTop ui__tooltipMiddle cards__tooltip">
Giant Snowball
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
rarity = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'profileCards__card'})
for r in rarity:
    print(r.find("div", {'class': 'profileCards__card'})["data-rarity"])
```

Comment: I tried this and it gives me                                                                              
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 49, in <module>
    print(r.find("div", {'class': 'profileCards__card'})["data-rarity"])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable